# Reading a list from a file, and converting it into a list of Python dictionaries

Tags: python, file-io, dictionary

Let's say I read from a file, called 'info.dat', containing this:

```
[{'name': 'Bob', 'occupation': 'architect', 'car': 'volvo'}, {'name': 'Steve', 'occupation': 'builder', 'car': 'Ford'}]
```

How could I read this and turn it into a list of dictionaries? If I do this:

```
with open('info.dat') as f:
    data = f.read()
```

It just reads it into a single string, and even if I do this to break it up:

```
data = data[1:-1]
data = data.split('},')
```

I still have to get it into a dictionary. Is there a better/cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Elaborate your question. It is already a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `ast.literal_eval` which can read simple Python literals such as dicts/tuples/lists - while not as "powerful" as `eval` it is safer due to its more restrictive nature.

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open('yourfile') as fin:
    your_list = literal_eval(fin.read())
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast
with open('info.dat') as f:
    data = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
```

As said in the docs, this is much more safer than the docs as it "safely evaluate[s] an expression node or a string containing a Python expression".

If it is unsafe, it will raise an error.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use eval -

```
eval("ld ="+open("info.dat").read())
```

Then access the list using `ld` variable